# How to filter on NULL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
"order (S)","method (NULL)","time (L)"
"/1553695740/Bar","true","[  { ""N"" : ""1556593200"" },  { ""N"" : ""1556859600"" }]"
"/1556439461/adasd","true","[  { ""N"" : ""1556593200"" },  { ""N"" : ""1556679600"" }]"
"/1556516482/Foobar","cheque","[  { ""N"" : ""1556766000"" }]"
```

How do I scan or query for that matter on empty "method" attribute values? https://s.natalian.org/2019-04-29/null.mp4

Comment: Do you mean method is an attribute name with value NULL? Generally, DynamoDB doesn't allow to save NULL value on attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the DynamoDB console offers a simple GUI and assumes the operations you want to perform all have the same type. When you select filters on columns of type "NULL", it only allows you to do exists or not exists.  This makes sense since a column containing only NULL datatypes can either exist or not exist.

What you have here is a column that contains multiple datatypes (since NULL is a different datatype than String).  There are many ways to filter what you want here but I don't believe they are available to you on the console.  Here is an example on how you could filter the dataset via the AWS CLI (note: since your column is a named a reserved word `method`, you will need to alias it with an expression attribute name):

## Using Filter expressions

```sh
$ aws dynamodb scan --table-name plocal --filter-expression '#M = :null' --expression-attribute-values '{":null":{"NULL":true}}' --expression-attribute-names '{"#M":"method"}'
```

An option to consider to avoid this would be to update your logic to write some of sort filler string value instead of a null or empty string when writing your data to the database (i.e. "None" or "N/A").  Then you could solely operate on Strings and search on that value instead.

DynamoDB currently does not allow String values of an empty string and will give you errors if you try and put those items directly. To make this "easier", many of the SDKs have provided mappers/converters for objects to DyanmoDB items and this usually involves converting empty strings to Null types as a way of working around the rule of no empty strings.

If you need to differentiate between `null` and `""`, you will need to write some custom logic to marshall/unmarshall empty strings to a unique string value (i.e. `"__EMPTY_STRING"`) when they are stored in DyanmoDB.

Comment: When a string is empty dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap from https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute creates this NULL.

Comment: [hendry@t480s db]$ aws --profile dd dynamodb scan --table-name plocal --filter-expression 'method = :null' --expression-attribute-values '{":null":{"NULL":true
}}'

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: method

Comment: Ah, method is a reserved word in DynamoDB so you'll need to alias that column, I will update my answer with this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that there is no way to filter using the console. But I'm guessing that what you really want is to use such a filter in code.

DynamoDB has a very peculiar way of storing NULLs. There is a "NULL" data type which basically represents the *concept* of null values but it really is sort of like a boolean.

If you have the opportunity to change the data type of that attribute to be a string, or numeric, I strongly recommend doing so. Then you'll be able to create much more powerful queries with filter conditions to match what you want.

If the data already exists and you don't have a significant number of items that need to be updated, I recommend creating a new attribute to represent your data and backfilling.

Just following up on the comments. If you prefer using the mapper, you can customize how it marshals certain attributes that may be null/empty. Have a look at the go sdk encoder implementation for some examples: https://git.codingcafe.org/Mirrors/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/9b5aaeba7a51edcf3f87bda525a08b04b90d2ef8/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/encode.go

Comment: When a string is empty dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap from https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute creates this NULL.

Comment: The mapper can be configured to generate custom mappings. That shouldn’t be an issue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this inside a FilterExpression:

`attribute_type(MyProperty, :nullType)` - Where `:nullType` is a string with value `NULL`. This one finds null entries.

`attribute_type(MyProperty, :stringType)` - Where `:stringType` is a string with value `S`. This one finds non-null entries.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax