# How to filter for empty values with the Golang filter builder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

Carrying on from [How to filter on NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898187/how-to-filter-on-null) I am struggling to replicate the Go code to filter for null values of a particular column:

```
import (
        "github.com/apex/log"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/endpoints"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/expression"
)

// aws --profile dd dynamodb scan --table-name plocal2 --filter-expression 'paymentmethod = :null' --expression-attribute-values '{":null" :{"NULL":true}}'

var table = "plocal2"

func main() {
        cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig(external.WithSharedConfigProfile("dd"))
        if err != nil {
                log.WithError(err).Fatal("setting up credentials")
                return
        }
        cfg.Region = endpoints.ApSoutheast1RegionID
        db := dynamodb.New(cfg)
        filt := expression.Name("paymentmethod").Equal(expression.Value(expression.Null))
        expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().
                WithFilter(filt).
                Build()
        if err != nil {
                log.WithError(err).Error("failed to build expression")
                return
        }
        scanReq := db.ScanRequest(&dynamodb.ScanInput{
                ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
                FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
                TableName:                 aws.String(table),
        })
        result, err := scanReq.Send()
        if err != nil {
                log.WithError(err).Error("failed to query table")
                return
        }
        log.Infof("%d", len(result.Items))
}
```

The error is:

```
2019/04/30 16:59:54 error failed to query table     error=ValidationException: Invalid FilterExpression: An expression attribute name used in the document path
 is not defined; attribute name: #0
        status code: 400, request id: 8CFTOAGVB7M1IM3DC6BFPEVLUNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG
```

Any tips how to debug this or where I am going wrong using the [expression builder](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/expression)?

Really wish there were [examples](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/expression#pkg-examples), since filtering on NULL should be a pretty common use case to me if one is using [MarshalMap](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute#MarshalMap) since empty strings becomes NULLs!

Answer (score 2):

`#better-late-than-never`, in hopes of helping others who, like me, struggled to [discover the secret](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/dbb8029634cbd92384bad24f743737345aca30b8/feature/dynamodb/expression/operand.go#L145-L146) to filtering dynamoDB `NULL` values with the `aws-sdk-go-v2` `expression` package:

```golang
filt := expression.Name("paymentmethod").
        Equal(expression.Value(&types.AttributeValueMemberNULL{Value: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

in aws-sdk-go (v1) https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/service/dynamodb/expression/condition.go#L71

`expresion.Null`

Example:

```
const endTsField = "end_ts"
filterNoEndTime := expression.Name(endTsField).AttributeNotExists()
filterNull := expression.Name(endTsField).NotEqual(expression.Value(expression.Null))
filterEndTime := expression.Name(endTsField).GreaterThanEqual(expression.Value(time.Now().UTC().UnixMilli()))
filter := filterNoEndTime.Or(filterEndTime).Or(filterNull)
```